# If no input don't display?

Tags: functions

First of all i am sorry if my question is not correct formulated, i am new in to wordpress and php. I hope i am not being too silly.

i have this:

```
<div class="propsmeta clearfix">
        <div class="propslist"><span>Locatie- </span> <span class="propval"> <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Tip proprietate- </span> <span class="propval"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'property', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Camere - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'bedrooms', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Băi - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php $bath=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_bath', true); echo $bath; ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Garaj - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php $garage=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_garage', true); echo $garage; ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Pret- </span> <span class="propval"> <?php $price=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_price', true); echo $price; ?></span></div>
        <div class="propslist"><span>Suprafata- </span> <span class="propval"> <?php $suprafata=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_suprafata', true); echo $suprafata; ?></span></div>
    </div>
```

I want if the input data is empty i don't want to be desplayd in the main div

For example if the bath input data is left empty  i want the:

```
<div class="propslist"><span>Băi - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php $bath=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_bath', true); echo $bath; ?></span></div>
```

not to appear anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $bath=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_bath', true); 
if(!empty($bath) ) { ?>

<div class="propslist"><span>Băi - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php  echo $bath; ?></span></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Do something like this for each div !.. only display div if the data to be displayed in div is not empty !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $bath=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_bath', true);
  if ($bath) { ?>
 <div class="propslist"><span>Băi - </span> <span class="propval"> <?php echo $bath; ?></span></div>
<?php } ?>
```